# What is the purpose of "-path ... -prune"?

Tags: shell, find

The command is:

```
find $HOME -path $HOME/$dir_name -prune -o -name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;
```

The variables `dir_name` and `file_suffix` are assigned a path to a directory and an arbitrary word earlier in the script.

I do not understand what the purpose of `-path $HOME/$dir_name` is, or how it affects how the rest of the command is interpreted.

Comment: see https://man.cx/find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-path $HOME/$dir_name -prune
```

excludes `$HOME/$dir_name` from the search; which makes sense because otherwise

```
-name "*$file_suffix" -exec cp {} $HOME/$dir_name/ \;
```

would select files copied to `$HOME/$dir_name` before and attempt to copy them again.

Answer (score 2):

The `-path` predicate allows you to specify a condition on what patterns to match. It's vaguely similar to the `-name` predicate, but applies to the full path, not just the file's name (basename).

Your specific command applies `-prune` to a specific subpath, so it will avoid scanning that particular subdirectory.  If this predicate fails, it will proceed with the predicates after `-o` (as in "or").

You should still [quote your variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)